# The group should be able to demonstrate how the PeerUnit tool framework is used for testing peer to peer systems

Tags: github

How the PeerUnit tool framework is used for testing peer to peer systems.

I tried to build it using github but didn't pass while running library not work and i would like to describe how peerunit is used for testing in peer to peer systems

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.